# How do you choose a specialization for a district?

Tags: cities-skylines

I'm trying to set a specialization on a district, but there doesn't seem to be an option to change it. I've supposedly unlocked the agriculture and foresting specializations. All I see in the district menu is "No specialization", with no apparent option to choose one.

How do I set a specialization?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I just figured this out.

So you see the 'Districts' menu at the bottom of the screen? It's next to the 'Zoning' button.

When you click on it, a number of options will appear above it, the first one allows you to 'paint' a plain-jane district, with the second being 'Erase District' and the remaining ones are for specializations. If you've unlocked the other specializations, all you need to do is to click the one you want, say 'Agriculture', and then click on an existing district or paint a new one.